# Automatic Web content downloading using C#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

I want to develop a program to automatically lookup words in Longman online dictionary and copy its definition and meanings. I am using visual studio and C# language and I have developed the part which browse to the website and search for a word. However, the problem is in navigating through Longman online website when there are some word forms. for example for [this link](http://www.ldoceonline.com/search/?q=superman) the html code of the suggested words is as following:

```
    <div class="content1">
  <style>
    .dictionary-results-title .topic_bullet {
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
    <div class="border-search">
        <div class="dictionary-results-title">
            Results from the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English:
        </div>

        <div class="dictionary-results-title">
            <span class="dictionary-results-title-topic-new">
                Click on topic labels to navigate through our Topic Dictionary
            </span>
        </div>
          <!-- google_ad_section_start -->
        <div id="42385" class="folded">
            <table id="hwdfolded" class="hwdfolded" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
                <tr>  
                    <td class="hwdunSelHG"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelHM"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelHD"></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>  
                    <td class="hwdunSelMG"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelMM">
                        <a href="/dictionary/superman">
                        <span class="headword">superman</span></a> 
                        <span class="homographs"></span> 
                        <span class="wordclass">noun</span>
                        <span class="topiclinks"></span>
                    </td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelMD"></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>    
                    <td class="hwdunSelBG"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelBM"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelBD"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> 
        <div id="42386" class="folded">
            <table id="hwdfolded" class="hwdfolded" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
                <tr>  
                    <td class="hwdunSelHG"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelHM"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelHD"></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>  
                    <td class="hwdunSelMG"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelMM">
                        <a href="/dictionary/Superman">
                        <span class="headword">Superman</span></a> 
                        <span class="homographs"></span> 
                        <span class="wordclass"></span>
                        <span class="topiclinks"></span>
                    </td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelMD"></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>  
                    <td class="hwdunSelBG"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelBM"></td> 
                    <td class="hwdunSelBD"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
            parent.curEntryId=42385; parent.prevEntryId=42385; parent.nextEntryId=42385; 
            parent.gsSenseId=null; parent.giPhrId=null; 
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have found the way to find the ID of the words like `id="42385"` and `id="42386"` but I cannot navigate through them. There is a table inside each element with these ids. As you can see in the html code the second data of the second row of the table contains the links for each word. 
the code I have written to click on them is like this:

```
HtmlElement Word = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hwdfolded");
foreach (HtmlElement ele in Word.Parent.Parent.Children)
{                
    if (ele.Id != null && ele.InnerText.ToLower().Contains(Stword))
    {
        HtmlElement clickon = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(ele.Id);
        clickon.InvokeMember("click");
        //ele.InvokeMember("click");
        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive)
            Application.DoEvents();
        do
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that Stword contains the string of the word I am searching for in this example it contains "superman" and also the ele.Id contains one the specified Ids and I checked it in debug mode. But the click command not works. I will appreciate it if you can tell me the solution or give me another solution which is better.

Comment: [Terms and conditions](https://www.pearson.com/uk/legal-notice.html) of Longman online dictionary clearly state that "Users may not create a database in electronic or structured manual form by systematically downloading and storing all or any of the content". So what you are doing is against their T&C.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it breaks the copyright of Longman online dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use a scraping tool to perform the navigation through the page. With [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) it is really easy to obtain elements by XPATH and navigate through them and also obtain the text inside them. Hope it helps.